# changing corner radius of uitableview grouped in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've tried using the following code but with no luck. Anybody know how to do this in iOS 6? I *do not* want to create a custom cell.

```
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    [self.tableView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

**Edit:**

It appears that what's actually happening is that this code is creating a corner radius for the entire view, not each individual UITableViewSection. Does this make sense?

I have also tried `[cell.layer setCornerRadius:3.0];` but also with no luck. The corners of my UITableView are still exactly the same.

[image]

Comment: May i ask why you do not want a custom cell? It makes life so much easier

Comment: @RobvanderVeer I've had difficulty using custom cells in the past, but I suppose I'd be open to suggestions using a custom cell. I'm primarily worried about performance issues. People have suggested using custom images for the entire cell and this seems like a lazy and incorrect way to about about solving this problem.

Comment: I would suggest to open a playground project and experiment, so youcan make a better decision.

Comment: Are you trying to round the corners of the entire tableview, a portion of the tableview, one of the tableview's "sections"? Can you clarify this?

Comment: Why you don't use custom cells with images?

Comment: the screenshot you are showing is of ios 7 , do u really wants it in ios 6 Or 7.?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change de backgroundView of the TableViewCell, create a subclass of UIView and change the layer class:

```
@interface BackgroundView : UIView
@end

@implementation BackgroundView

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}
@end
```

later in cellForRowAtIndexPath you do something like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

CGRect frame = cell.backgroundView.frame;
cell.backgroundView = [[BackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

CGFloat corner = 20.0f;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.backgroundView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(corner, corner)];
CAShapeLayer  *shapeLayer = (CAShapeLayer *)cell.backgroundView.layer;
shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
shapeLayer.fillColor = cell.textLabel.backgroundColor.CGColor;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0f;

return cell;
```

Results this:

[image]

You can modify the corners you want or create another path.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am not sure as to why this answer has been accepted. The OP asked if you can apply cornerRadius to grouped cells, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 5):

who said `[_tblView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];` is not working in grouped style tableView.

Write this code and you will set setCornerRadius also works in grouped tableView.

```
[_tblView setBackgroundView:nil];
[_tblView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[_tblView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

[image]

`[_tblView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];` will not create corner radius for particular section of tableView this is for setting corner radius of whole tableView.

Comment: How to set corner radius for tableview section ?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your .h file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And use below in your code,

```
tblView.layer.cornerRadius=5.0f;
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of setting the corner radius of the cell, set the radius for the cell.contentview as follows:

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
```

put the above code while initializing the cell.

Answer (score 2):

add quartzcore framework to your project

```
import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h to your .h file
```

self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing this line of code :

```
[self.tableView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

First you Need to use the QuartzCode Framework Import that Framework ANd Declare .h File Which class you wanted to set the Layer Effect.

And Add that Method

```
myTableView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
[myTableView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

and if you want to set corner radious to cell also tried this code

UITableViewCell.layer is kind of class CALayer and CALayer class have a property called cornerRadius. so you set the cell's corner radius as fallows:

```
[cell.layer setCornerRadius:3.0];
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do by this. Its working for me

```
    UILabel *delLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
    delLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18];
    delLbl.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    delLbl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    delLbl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    delLbl.text = @"Cell Text";
    delLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:delLbl];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    Return Cell;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think PrettyKit is what you're looking for. Fully customisable and fast. https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit give it a go. Should do the job properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
tableView.layer.cornerRadius=5.0f;
```