# How to set roundeed corner for first and last cell of UItableView's Section

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

How can i achieve following in ios 7 ??? I want rounded corners around uitableview for first and last cell only.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 7 does not support rounded corners in grouped tables anymore.

iOS 7 is a major overhaul of the whole GUI. Many things have changed, including the appearance of the UITableViews.

You can try to create a custom cell which draws a rounded rect. You have to identifiy the first and last cell in your TableView and only draw the custom View, Background, whatever for those cells.

How to customize the appearance of the UITableView was also discussed here:
[changing corner radius of uitableview grouped in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095223/changing-corner-radius-of-uitableview-grouped-in-ios6)

*Although this link is for iOS 6 the mechanic should be the same in iOS7.*

Answer (score 2):

It is basically a UItableView that have a rounded corner.

Import quartz Core framework and try to change the corner radius of the tableView itself using tableView.layer.cornerRadius = float value;

Comment: I tried this. but it leaves bottom as it is. I am just unable to remove footer from table.

Comment: To remove the footer set its height to 0.0.    tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the tableView