# Corner Radius is not working in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode4.5

I want to make my tableViewCell with rounded corner. It is work fine upto iOS6. But in iOS7 rounded corners are not shown.

I used

```
((UIView*)[self viewWithTag:200]).layer.cornerRadius = 8;    
((UIView*)[self viewWithTag:200]).layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: If you log the view, is it nil?

Comment: Did you think about the expense of using `viewWithTag:` and consider getting a single reference to the view first?  This would also aid debugging, as per David Caunt's suggestion.

Comment: @DavidCaunt : No, it is not nil.

Comment: Did you set the border width?

Comment: probabaly you was going to type this `((UIView*)[self viewWithTag:200]).masksToBounds = YES;` instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this category. For me it is working for all iOS.

```
- (void)setRoundedBorder:(float) radius borderWidth:(float)borderWidth color:(UIColor*)color
{
    CALayer * l = [self layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:radius];
    // You can even add a border
    [l setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
    [l setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 does not support rounded corners in grouped tables anymore.

iOS 7 is a major overhaul of the whole GUI. Many things have changed, including the appearance of the UITableViews.

You can try to create a custom cell which draws a rounded rect. You have to identifiy the first and last cell in your TableView and only draw the custom View, Background, whatever for those cells.

Here is a link that may help you, although it is targeted for iOS 6:

[changing corner radius of uitableview grouped in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095223/changing-corner-radius-of-uitableview-grouped-in-ios6)