# Rounded UITableViewCell corners (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to curve the corners of my UITableViewCells, but I don't know how to do it. Also, as of now, I don't want to use xib/nib.

I have tried with:

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show your image, What you want to achieve?

Comment: It should work with `cell.contentView`. However, it would be better to add a container view inside and do it on that.

Comment: you can use `collectionView` instead of `tableView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a corner radius for a custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355386/how-to-set-a-corner-radius-for-a-custom-cell)

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact it is actually working however you need to change

- Either the cell background color from default to clear as below

[image]

- Or the cell content view background color from default to clear as below

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but if you want to show a rounded table you need to set the border width, try this:

```
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

if the width is not set you won't see a rounder corners.

Comment: `borderWidth` does not have anything to do with rounded corners.